# Easiest way to disable JS completely when browsed via IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

My website has somewhat graceful degradation in the sense that if JS is disabled, a fallback technique is used and everything is dandy. The problem arises when JS is enabled but poorly supported (*cough* IE6 *cough*). Is there a quick and dirty way of just disabling JS entirely on my website when the user is browsing with an unsupported browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap all the scripts you use in a conditional comment:

```
<![if gt IE 6]>
   <script type="text/javascript"...></script>
   ...
<![endif]>
```

For non-IE browsers, the conditional is ignored entirely and the `script` element is processed normally. On IE, the conditional is evaluated, and the `script` element is processed if IE is "greater than" 6. [Details here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) One advantage to this method is that IE6 and lower won't even bother to download the script file.

Comment: Right concept, but the comment you've provided hides the script from everything *except* IE6 and lower. :-) You meant: `<![if gt IE 6]><script ...><![endif]>`. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: Oh, right... It's too early for correct thinking in IE terms .. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a more elegant solution? Sorry to sound like I'm pandering, but just wondering.

Comment: Well, that depends on your definition of elegant. Conditional comments are a very well understood and seasoned practice, as they work reliably for every case. You could do it on the backend, checking for the user client and then omitting the HTML output of the scripts all together, but apart from that... You can't actually __turn off__ the javascript in your client's browser - only he can do that.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi What is more elegant than this? :)

Comment: Something you only write once, instead of littering your pages with this each and every time.

Comment: Well - if you were using a template engine, you'd actually had to write this only once. But as I said, you can't turn it off. You can just avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
//run your javascript
```

Comment: Why are you providing a jQuery-based answer to a question that was not tagged with jQuery?  The whole world doesn't use jQuery or care to or need to.